# What is the best way to insert/update rows in Cassandra table via Java + Spark + SparkSession

Tags: java, apache-spark, cassandra, cql

This is the way how to get data from cassandra table via *Java + Spark + SparkSession*:

```
SparkSession spark = SparkSession
          .builder()
          .appName("JavaDemoDataSet")
          .config("spark.sql.warehouse.dir", "/file:C:/temp")
          .config("spark.cassandra.connection.host", "127.0.0.1")
          .config("spark.cassandra.connection.port", "9042")
          .master("local[2]")
          .getOrCreate();

 Dataset<Row> dataset = spark.read()
        .format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra")
        .options(new HashMap<String, String>() {
            {
                put("keyspace", "chat");
                put("table", "dictionary");
            }
        })
        .load()
        .filter("value_id BETWEEN 1 AND 5");
```

But when I'm researching how to add or modify rows in this table (at least 1 row) - I could not find out what is the best way to do that.
For example I'm developing simple application with GUI and I need to add a new value to the "Dictionary" table. So, in this case, from my point of view - I don't need a DataSet to do that.

When I'm researching how to add one single row via SparkSession - I could not find Java+Spark+Sparksession examples how to do that.
I definitely could do that with the CQL statement via *Statement*, but which one way to do that is the best to update or add 1 or 2 rows? Especially when I'm using SparkSession to read them.

I'll really appreciate examples (or even hyperlinks, I researched a lot, but may be I missed something important), if possible, cause I'm pretty new to all that.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would strongly recommend not using Spark to do a single row update. The built in connector methods are oriented around large mounts of data and will probably be very inefficient with single row changes.. You are much better off just using the driver directly or working with the CassandraConnector interface.

https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/master/doc/1_connecting.md#connecting-manually-to-cassandra

Answer (score 2):

Here is the sample for save and read using Java+SparkSession+CassandraConnector.

```
public class SparkCassandraDatasetApplication {
public static void main(String[] args) {
     SparkSession spark = SparkSession
      .builder()
      .appName("SparkCassandraDatasetApplication")
      .config("spark.sql.warehouse.dir", "/file:C:/temp")
      .config("spark.cassandra.connection.host", "127.0.0.1")
      .config("spark.cassandra.connection.port", "9042")
      .master("local")
      .getOrCreate();

    //Data
    MyData data = new MyData();
    data.setId("111");
    data.setUsername("userOne");
    List<MyData> users = Arrays.asList(data);
    Dataset<MyData> datasetWrite = spark.createDataset(users, Encoders.bean(MyData.class));

    //Save data to Cassandra
    datasetWrite.write().format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra").options(new HashMap<String, String>() {
        {
            put("keyspace", "mykeyspace");
            put("table", "mytable");
        }
    }).mode(SaveMode.Append).save();

    //Read data back
    Dataset<Row> datasetRead = spark.read().format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra")
            .options(new HashMap<String, String>() {
                {
                    put("keyspace", "mykeyspace");
                    put("table", "mytable");
                }
            }).load();

    datasetRead.show();
    spark.stop();
   }
}
```

Comment: thank you for the answer, just one thing - I got only last one row in my database when I got 6 in DataSet, what should I do with it? `System.out.println("dataset items amount: " + datasetWrite.count());// I got 6 in my console here
  
  //Save data to Cassandra
  datasetWrite.write().format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra")
  .options(new HashMap<String, String>() {
      {
          put("keyspace", "chat");
          put("table", "dictionary");
      }
  }).mode(SaveMode.Append).save();`

Comment: Check your data otherwise code should work fine. SaveMode.Append will append the data if it already exist in DB.

Comment: fixed, thank you! I thought I should use foreach to resolve my problem